# How do I find all .exe files using the boost library?

Tags: c++, boost

What is boost's function similar to `FindFirstFile`? I want find `*.exe` in a folder using boost.

For example :

```
HANDLE handle = FindFirstfile(buf, &finds);
while(FindNextFile(handle, &finds) { // using file }
```

Comment: So you know about Boost but [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/) wasn't an obvious candidate?

Comment: I've edited your question for quality and formatting. In the future, please see the help available in the editor, as well as the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) (in particular, pay close attention to the 'how to ask' section).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the directory_iterator:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

...

path mypath("/where/ever/");

for(directory_iterator it( mypath ); ; ++it) {
    ...
}
```

and match with your criteria.